# Buddypress - getting members loop to print members in specific order by specific criteria

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am building a site for students to find teachers.  I want to be able to filter the teachers based on custom criteria.  One of the criteria I'd like to be able to filter them by is user ratings.  I have written a custom function to get the exact order of members I want displayed, in this case by user rating.

I know that in using bp_has_members, you can pass custom values into its query string.  I've done this successfully before using "&include=1,2,3" where 1,2,3 is a string of user_ids that I was able to filter by some criteria.  When using this include statement, and using the default ways that Buddypress orders members - by last active, alphabetical, and newest registered, this works great.  But in trying to sort users by ratings, I had to put these user ids in a different order.  Suppose the order of user ratings is 2 > 3> 1 - I passed in "&include=2,3,1" with no effect.

Does anybody out there know if there is a way to force the bp members-loop to spit out members in a specific, pre-determined order?  I have the order itself ready to go, just would love to get buddypress to execute the order.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do right now.
But BuddyPress 1.8 should contain extra filsters and hooks in BP_Query (that is used to get members/groups) and I think it will be possible.

BP 1.8 beta [was released](http://buddypress.org/2013/06/buddypress-1-8-beta1-is-now-available/) - take a look. According to that post:

> bp_has_groups() and bp_has_activities() now accept a meta_query parameter (#3521). This means you can filter a group or activity query based on groupmeta or activitymeta, using the very same meta_query syntax familiar from WP_Query.